# getting the user back where they came from with mod_form_auth

Tags: authentication, httpd

Using the mod_form_auth module in Apache HTTPD 2.4.3, I am looking for a way to have the user redirected to their original desired target after completing a login.

That is, if I have a

```
<Location /protected>
   ... form auth config here
</Location>
```

the user might browse to /protected/a, or to protected/b. In either case, they will be presented with the login form. However, as far as I can see, I must specific a single 'success' URL. I'm wondering if I'm missing some Apache feature that would allow me to, for example, cause the redirect to the login form go to something like:

```
https://login.html?origTarget=/protected/a
```

via some syntax on the `AuthForLoginRequiredLocation` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [AuthFormLocation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_auth_form.html#authformlocation) directive.

> The AuthFormLocation directive specifies the name of an HTML field
>   which, if present, will contain a URL to redirect the browser to
>   should login be successful.

Comment: how would that field end up containing the correct original URL that the user navigated to?

Comment: I imagine you will need to write this out using your server-side script. As I understand it `AuthFormLoginRequiredLocation` overrides the `ErrorDocument` directive. In an error document you can refer to `$_SERVER['REQUESTED_URI']` (PHP) to get the originally requested URL - does this work for you?